# single.php error

Tags: php

writingyourwaytosuccess.com/blog

Attempting to view a single post returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function atmosphere_posted_on() in
/home/content/46/7460046/html/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-2010/single.php on line 17
```

Thanks!

Comment: you know what to do, fixed that line... But if you don't know how -me too. Well, first of all, you are not clear with the problem.

Comment: Michael, it can be a lot of kind. Please could you please put the piece of the code containing the line 17 of your file single.php, so we can answer you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using this theme: [Atmosphere 2010](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/atmosphere-2010)

Looking through the theme files the function `atmosphere_posted_on` is used a couple times in loop.php and single.php.  The `undefined function` error indicates that the function does not exist which leads me to believe that your functions.php has been modified or is otherwise missing this function.  In the version I downloaded, the function looks like this in functions.php starting at line 281:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'atmosphere_posted_on' ) ) :

function atmosphere_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'atmosphere' ),
    'meta-prep meta-prep-author',sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
        get_permalink(),esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        get_the_date()),
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
            get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
            sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'atmosphere' ), get_the_author() ),
        get_the_author()));
}
endif;
```

You might try uploading a new version of functions.php or see if your modified version still contains this function.

Comment: Thank you chrishajer - 100% correct. The Atmosphere theme was using a functions.php file from the TwentyTen theme. It's surprising the blog single page was the only thing wrong!